# Abstract class as argument (interface case)

Tags: c++, interface, abstract-class

I have an abstract class supposed to be an interface, like this:

```
  class IDataSource
    {
    public:
        virtual double getMeThatDouble() = 0;
    }
```

and some implementations like

```
 class IDataSourceStreamer
    {
    public:
        double getMeThatDouble()
          {
            //implementation
          }
    }
```

The point is that I want to use it as initial parameter in constructor of other classes like

```
class DataNeeder
{
  public:
       explicit DataNeeder(IDataSource);
}
```

and here comes the trouble - `"parameter of abstract class type is not allowed"`.

I understand that it's forbidden for particular reason - using abstract class by itself is impossible. So what should I do? Is a method like

```
IDataSource.FeedThat(DataNeeder)
```

an only option? Kinda ugly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass the abstract type as either a reference or a pointer. For example:

```
class DataNeeder {
public:
    explicit DataNeeder(IDataSource &source) : source_(source) {
    }

    void someMethod() {
        double x = source_.getMeThatDouble();
        // ...
    }

private:
    IDataSource &source_;
}
```

Then you can have `DataNeeder`'s member functions operate on `source_`. As I mentioned, you can also use a pointer for this task, but I like to only use pointers for "OUT" parameters and things that can conceivable be `NULL`.